# Jquery not firing dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, delegates

I am currently working on an ASP.Net Application and the there a HTML Table is built on the fly.

Each of the table rows other than the header rows are to have the ability to be re sequenced. In the main this works, however the delegate events that I have written doesn't always fire and therefore the user can be clicking for some time before anything happens.

Please see my code and let me know where I have gone wrong with this as this needs to work consistently and for every browser.

```
$('td').on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function () {    

console.log("up or down arrow clicked");    

var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");    
var thisTable = row.closest("table");    
if ($(this).is(".up")) {    
    if (row[0].rowIndex > 1) {    
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());    
    }    
} else if ($(this).is(".down")) {    
    row.insertAfter(row.next());    
} else if ($(this).is(".top")) {    
    row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));    
    row.insertAfter(row.next());    
} else {    
    row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));    
}    

});
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1. Change `$('td').on('click',` to `$('table').on('click',`
2. Instead of `is('.top')`, you should check `hasClass('.top')`

Below is the updated code:

```
$('table').on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function() {

  console.log("up or down arrow clicked");

  var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
  var thisTable = row.closest("table");
  if ($(this).hasClass(".up")) {
    if (row[0].rowIndex > 1) {
      row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    }
  } else if ($(this).hasClass(".down")) {
    row.insertAfter(row.next());
  } else if ($(this).hasClass(".top")) {
    row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));
    row.insertAfter(row.next());
  } else {
    row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
  }

});
```

Comment: I dont see that i am using `is('.top')`, however I will try this, but just a question, why use `$('table')` over `$('td')` or `$(document)`

Comment: `$('table')` because, all your classes on which you are firing events are inside the table. If you use `document` this events will get binded to other elements having same class but are not inside `table`. And you are using `is('.top')` here `$(this).is(".top")`

Comment: oh yes, so I am. I was looking in your example for it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
$('td').on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function () {
```

try

```
$(document).on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code :

```
$('td').on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function () { ....
```

To :

```
$(document).on('click', "a.up, a.down, a.top, a.bottom", function () { ...
```